# dy/dx where y and x are BOTH independent variables

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Is $\frac{dx}{dy}$ meaningful if both x and y are independent variables, like if they represent coordinates on the x-axis and the y-axis?
Does this evaluate to zero? to one?

Comment: If $x$ does not depend on $y$ in any way then $\frac {dx}{dy}$ would be $0$.